# Javascript focus() não funciona em determinado trecho do código

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Neste código utilizo várias vezes o evento focus(), no entanto em um determinado trecho ele é ignorado, gostaria de saber por que?

***A linha que não funciona está comentada.***

```js
function CriaRequest() {
 try{
 request = new XMLHttpRequest();        
 }catch (IEAtual){
  try{
        request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");       
        }catch(IEAntigo){
         try{
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");          
            }catch(falha){
             request = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!request) 
    alert("Seu Navegador não suporta Ajax!");
    else
    return request;
}
function nome_existe() {
 
 if(!valida_nome()) { // caso seja inválido
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
 return;
 }
 var nome = document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value;
 var xmlreq = CriaRequest();
 xmlreq.open("GET", "mysqli_select_ajax.php?nome_cad=" + nome, true);
 xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xmlreq.readyState == 4 && xmlreq.status == 200){
      document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value='';
   document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = xmlreq.responseText;
  }
  if(document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder == "Nome já existe!"){
   document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
/*Essa linha abaixo funciona, porém o focus() acima não, ele escreve o placeholder e pula pro próximo campo*/
   document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = "Esse funciona, mas não o focus";
  }
     
 }
 xmlreq.send(null);

 
}
function valida_nome(){
 var filter_nome = /^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9]|\s)+$/ ;
 if(!filter_nome.test(document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value)){
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value='';
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = "Nome inválido";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.outline = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").onkeydown = function keydown_nome(){
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.borderColor = "#999999";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.outline = null;
    }
 return false; 
 }
 return true;
}
function email_existe() {
 
 if(!valida_email()) { // caso seja inválido
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").focus();
 return;
 }
 var email = document.getElementById("input_email_cad").value;
 var xmlreq = CriaRequest();
 xmlreq.open("GET", "mysqli_select_ajax.php?email_cad=" + email, true);
 xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xmlreq.readyState == 4 && xmlreq.status == 200){
      if(xmlreq.responseText == "Email já existe!"){
       document.getElementById("input_email_cad").value='';
    document.getElementById("input_email_cad").placeholder = xmlreq.responseText;
    document.getElementById("input_email_cad").focus();
      }
     }
  return true;
     };
     xmlreq.send(null);
}

function valida_email(){
 var filter_email = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i ;
 if(!filter_email.test(document.getElementById("input_email_cad").value)){
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").value='';
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").placeholder = "Email inválido";
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").style.outline = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").focus();
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").onkeydown = function keydown_email(){
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").style.borderColor = "#999999";
 document.getElementById("input_email_cad").style.outline = null;
 }
 return false; 
 }
 return true;
}
function valida_email_conf(){  
  if((form_user_cad.conf_email_cad.value) != (form_user_cad.email_cad.value)){
  document.getElementById("input_conf_email_cad").value='';
  document.getElementById("input_conf_email_cad").placeholder = "Email diferente";
  document.getElementById("input_conf_email_cad").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
  document.getElementById("input_conf_email_cad").style.outline = "#ff0000";
  document.getElementById("input_conf_email_cad").focus();
  document.getElementById("input_conf_email_cad").onkeydown = function keydown_email_conf(){
    document.getElementById("input_conf_email_cad").style.borderColor = "#999999";
   document.getElementById("input_conf_email_cad").style.outline = null;
   } 
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
 <script src="valida_user_ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<form id="form_user_cad" name="form_user_cad" method="POST"  action="recebe_form_user.php" >
 <input type="text" id="input_nome_cad" name="nome_cad" placeholder="Nome e Sobrenome" autofocus onblur="nome_existe()"><br/>
 <input type="text" id="input_email_cad" name="email_cad" placeholder="Insira o Email" onblur="email_existe()"><br/>
 <input type="submit"  class="btn_enviar_cad"  name="enviar_cad"  value="Criar Conta"  >
</form>
```

Minha intenção é se o teste no IF acima for true ele muda o placeholder e mantém o focus nesse campo, mudar o placeholder ele muda, mas não mantém o focus no campo que eu desejo, se alguém puder ajudar...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v8q4uuz1/1/ testei e funcionou

Comment: Quando é que fica com "Nome já existe!" no placeholder?

Comment: document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = xmlreq.responseText;   }   if(document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder == "Nome já existe!") //sendo que responseText, é o resultado da consulta no banco, que retorna ou o nome digitado casa não exista no banco ou "Nome já existe!"

Comment: Não entendi o que quis dizer com essa linha: `linha abaixo funciona, porém o focus() acima não, ele escreve o placeholder e pula pro próximo campo*/`. Você está obtendo o `ìnput` nome, e o placeholder e o focus estão nele. Deveria mudar para o e-mail? Qual o comportamento para um nome que já exista, limpar o campo? Prosseguir?

Comment: @Randrade começando 3 linhas acima do comentário...->document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = xmlreq.responseText;/*pega a resposta(pode ser o nome que o cara digitou se não existir ou a mensagem string "Nome já existe! ") do banco de dados pelo xmlreq.responseText e põe no placeholder*/->if(document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder == "Nome já existe!"){/*Se o placeholder recebeu "Nome já existe!"->document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();/*isso não acontece ou se acontece ele acontece , mas avança, não sei, queria que ficasse em foco nesse input*/-

Comment: >document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = "Esse funciona, mas não o focus";/*essa mensagem se vier a string "Nome já existe"através do xmlreq.responseText, fica no placeholder*/ A ideia geral é o usuário põe o nome no input se passa no regex vai verificar se tem o nome no banco, se não tiver no banco, mantém o nome digitado no placeholder e

Comment: pula pro próximo campo, se tiver o nome no banco, ou não passa no regex, o campo nome_cad fica com focus(), bordas e outline vermelhos com a mensagem "Nome já existe!" ou "Nome inválido" no placeholder, e quando o user começa a digitar aciona o "onkeydown" que bota a borda e outline para o css original para realizar a checagem novamente*/

Comment: @Randrade consegui joguei o focus fora do bloco da instrução que faz a comparação....Vlw